# Using Ionic Livereload Causes Blank Page

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

When I use the livereload option on ionic my iOS app appears as a blank page. How can this be fixed? The app loads fine in the emulator and when being run directly from xcode. The error message that appears in the console is:

**Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had selected the wrong ip address for the ionic run command. To reset the ip address type in the command:

**ionic address**

Then select the correct ip address from the list of options. For me I had to select option 1 instead of option 2.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to a similar problem is that this can happen when the device needs the internet but isn't connected to any wifi source.